# Android Virtual Device Manager not getting started

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, android-virtual-device

I have created an AVD named MyAVD , but when I tried to start the AVD I am getting the below error
Starting emulator for AVD 'MyAVD'
PANIC: Could not open: MyAVD

My AVD is located in C:\Users\Anoob.android\avd
And my Android SDK located in C:\Users\Anoob\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I cannot solve your error, but I recommend you to use **Genymotion** instead of standard Android Emulator. It is incredibly fast, starts withing 30 seconds and will be recognised as a real device.

Comment: Its not worked out for me.